# Error while calling function in smart contract using nodejs?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js

I have deployed a contract in private blockchain using mist wallet.
When I try to call the function in the smart contract using web3 api it through the below error

```
/home/karthikeyan/Desktop/n2/node_modules/web3/lib/solidity/address.js:23
return !!name.match(/address(\[([0-9]*)\])?/);
             ^                                               
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
 at SolidityTypeAddress.isType
```

My code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new 
Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://54.212.192.158:8545"));

var abi = [ Contract ABI];

var myContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var myContractInstance = myContract.at("0x1AAFef75Fd4349F1747F051819B0E6DDb9903826");
var result = myContractInstance.balanceOf("0x7F0991e4c4613fbD4B84bb3B3f195f104936ABe7");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that name is undefined. Try logging out variable `name` right before you call it to see what the problem might be.